# Logic type problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A school has 90 children.During the day each child attends 4 classes.Each class has 15 children and 1 teacher.During the day each teacher has 3 classes.What is the smalles number of teachers the school can have and why. I got 6 teachers because I divided 90 by 15 but, im not sure if this is correct.Thanks!

Comment: http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/misc/Miscellaneous_Word_Problems.faq.question.260679.html

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is wrong because you forget to consider that the student must attend $4$ classes and that professors can teach $3$ classes per day.

So if you want to find the minimal number of professors needed then it is $\frac{90*4}{15*3}=8$

Answer (score 0):

6 is what you get if each child has only 1 class. But each child has 4 classes so you need to multiply 6 by 4 and you get 24, meaning that 24 is the minimum number of classes that you need to give 90 kids 4 different classes with each class having 15 children. Now since each teacher teaches 3 class you divide 24 by 3 and you get your answer, 8.